# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: android, date

In my project, I am trying to parse date format like this "Mon Oct 20 00:00:00 GMT+06:30 2014" to dd-MM-yyyy but I got the following error. I am hoping someone to solve me this problem.

Thanks,

```
10-20 13:03:01.390: W/System.err(23409): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Mon Oct 20 00:00:00 GMT+06:30 2014" (at offset 0)
```

parseDate.java

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter_date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String sdate="Mon Oct 20 00:00:00 GMT+06:30 2014";
    try {
        Date _date= formatter_date.parse(sdate);
        holder.txtDate.setText(String.valueOf(_date));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: can we see the declaration of `formatter_date`?

Comment: @cosmincalistru I just added formatter_date, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this code

```
public static String parseTodaysDate(String time) {



    String inputPattern = "EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";

    String outputPattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";

    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern);
    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);

    Date date = null;
    String str = null;

    try {
        date = inputFormat.parse(time);
        str = outputFormat.format(date);

        Log.i("mini", "Converted Date Today:" + str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: @MeenalSharma,I think you miss one 'd' inputPattern.

Comment: @MeenalSharma , change your parsing format `dd` instead of `d`

Comment: NB : if the error persists you have to add the local information pour the inputFormat.  `SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(inputPattern, Locale.ENGLISH); `

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter_date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

with

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter_date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Because that's the way the string is made. The input value would have to be formatted that way. But the input is not "20-10-2014"...

Comment: Great answer, simply true!